# Squaring the odd number and squaring the number-1 if number is even

Tags: python

Function called odd_square which takes one number as a parameter.

If the number is odd, it returns the square (power of two) of the number.

If the number is even, it returns (number-1) squared.

With an input of 7 the function should return 49. With an input of 6 the function should return 25.

```
def odd_square():
print('Squaring')
number = input("Enter an integer number: ")
s = number*number
q = number-1
if num % 2 == 0:
    return q*q

else:
    return s
```

TypeError: odd_square() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Looks like your program does what you want.

Comment: What is your question exactly? What problem with your code do you have? Unless it's a copying error, it looks like you might just be missing tabs on every line after your print statement.

Comment: The error is not in the function, but in the way you call it. Don't send it a number, but just call `odd_square()`, and it gets the number from the user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is easy sample code to understand:

```
def odd_square(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        return number*number
    else:
        return (number - 1)*(number - 1)

square = odd_square(int(input("Enter number to square: ")))
print("square is: ",square)
```

you need to convert `number` to `integer` as `input()` returns `string`.

```
TypeError: odd_square() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Your `odd_square()` function don't take any argument as per your `def`. It seems you are providing argument to `odd_square()` while calling it.

Comment below if you find it difficult to understand.

Comment: EOFError: EOF when reading a line.   How to solve this error even in other codes as well?

Comment: Where you are running code? just copy above code and paste it in test.py file and run it. Its working on my side.

Comment: @NiharikaAnand If you have another unrelated question, post a new question, following the guidence in this site. Don't write an irrelavent comment to someone's answer.